# How to use clsql and data-table together

Tags: common-lisp, clsql

I fail to comprehend how to use [data-table](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/data-table) with CLSQL. [CL-CSV repository README](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv) mentions that this is possible, but I would just really like an example.

f.e. If I have a data-table generated from a CSV in `*db*`, how do I use CLSQL to query the contents? I cannot even make CLSQL to use/connect to `*db*` as a database.